# Problems with WordPress wp nav menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a problem getting wp-nav-menu to work right. I have a css triangle in my menu design and so the menu is positioned farther down causing the menu to disappear before you get to it. To fix that I added some jQuery but now the menu will stay open if you open it then move the mouse above it. The website is located at: https://www.appshc.com/ Here is my Jquery code:

```
       $(function() {

        //menu bug fix

        $("li.menu-item").mouseover(function() {

            var submenu = $('.sub-menu');
            $(this).children('ul').show();

        });

        $("li.menu-item ul").mouseleave(function() {

            $("li.menu-item ul").delay(200).hide();          

        }); 
   });
```

This is the HTML generated By wordpress, sorry about the awful formatting

```
 <div class="menu-mainmenu-container">
   <ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="top-nav"><
   li id="menu-item-460" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page        menu-item-460"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/treatment-center-apps/">HEALTHCARE APPS</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-459"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/business-apps/">BUSINESS APPS</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-464"><a href="#">MORE APPS</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-458" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-458"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/music-apps/">MUSIC APPS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-457" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-457"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/church-apps/">CHURCH APPS</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-461"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/mobile-app-blog/">BLOG</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-462"><a href="https://www.appshc.com/contact/">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-463"><a href="#">GET STARTED</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

I had a couple ideas:

1) Try to use the jQuery HoverIntent plugin which I know almost nothing about but I keep reading about it however it is lacking in good tutorials.

2) Remove my Jquery code and add a wrapper div around the submenu with jQuery and position it farther up adding a margin to push submenu down so that the space is not there in view but there is no gam between the parent menu item and the submenu.

What route should I take for this and doesn anybody have any better solutions for this?

Comment: try to change `mouseleave` to `mouseout`, you know what, lets try something else. an answer is coming.

Comment: well.. i just went to your site and it works as is.. you made a change right?

Comment: check for js errors in your console

Comment: Eliran, yes I was waiting for an answer here for a bit and everyone was busy at the time so I tried a jquery .wrap() on the submenu then gave it a margin-top of -10. thats it, wham bam fixed and home for dinner. Thanks though:)